# Hairline graph after matrix transformation

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I'm testing the drawing of an XY graph on my Android tablet.  It's a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7") running ICS.

I've created a View subtype with an overridden onDraw method.  Its job is to simply plot an array of (x,y) coordinates as a series of connected line segments.  I've got a float array representing the y values, and the x values are the array indices.  The y values extend from -1 to 1 and there are about 10 values.  Pretty simple.

The target canvas is a square on the screen, say about 480 by 480 pixels, with +1 intended to be at the top of the screen and -1 at the bottom, and the 0th value at the extreme left and the Nth value at the extreme right.

Thus, the transformation from "world coordinates" to "screen coordinates" along the X and Y axes is not uniform.  In my onDraw method, I apply a translate, a scale, and then another translate operation to the Canvas object, and then I proceed to draw the line segments using a Paint pen having a hairline stroke width of 0.

The result is a graph that's not hairline in width.  Obviously, my scale operation is thickening the line segments so that gently sloping lines appear thicker than steep ones.  When I change my world-coordinates extents so that they're equal along both axes (to match the square canvas), then this problem disappears.

Interestingly, this problem occurs on the tablet, but not on the Android ICS emulator.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.  My preference is to have a hairline graph no matter what the transformation is.

Comment: FYI:  I think I noticed that this problem is confined to an Android 4.0.3 apk for the indicated device.  The problem goes away for the indicated device if the same app is built against Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious work-around to this issue is to leave the canvas's matrix untouched and perform the translate/scale/translate operations myself (converting from world to screen coordinates), and then use the screen coordinates for drawing, utilizing a Paint pen with a width of 0.